Эффективный стриминг видео с клиента на сервер для воспроизведения на других клиетнах
В приложении нужно транслировать запись экрана на сервер для пересылки этой трансляции другим клиентам. Я в теории могу просто кодировать этот снимок экрана каждый кадр в jpeg и отправлять на сервер просто как картинку, чтобы просто эта картинка всем пересылалась, но я чую что это будет довольно не эффективно. Думаю мудрить свои алгоритмы с каким то разбиением на плитки и синхронизацией только поменявшихся плиток стоит в последнюю очередь, т.к. врядли я переплюну в этом всякие mpeg и другие такие конторы. Так вот, какие вы можете назвать библиотеки обеспечивающие кодирование видео для стриминга покадрово и декодирование этого обратно в картинку. Какой должен быть механизм по моей задумке я получаю битмап экрана -> передаю его в byte[] library.encode(bitmap image) которая вернет данные которые нужно отправить на сервер -> на другом клиенте получаю эти обновления и делаю  bitmap library.decode(byte[] data). Какие библиотеки подходящие для этой задачи вы можете подсказать?

Можно найти готовые решения. Например, Screen capture to video. Это платформа UWP, но у вас не указано ничего, кроме C#.

@AlexanderPetrov я делаю на AvalniaUI, а захват экрана при помощи SharpDx, но не думаю что суть этого вопроса затрагивает конкретный фреймворк GUI. На сколько можно использовать MediaStreamSource для приложений не на UWP?
